# how to write event driven code that waits for the responses of 3 different ajax requests?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, callback

I have a webpage where I have 3 separate ajax calls

All 3 use the same structure:
     $.ajax({
            //this is the php file that processes the data and send mail
            url: url,

```
        //POST method is used
        type: "POST",

        //pass the data         
        data: data,     

        //Do not cache the page
        cache: false,

        //success
        success: function (json) {
```

I want to trigger another function but only if the 3 separate ajax calls are successful.

How do I go about doing that?

**Update:
I now have an issue when using $.when()**

My code now looks like this:

```
function mainFunction() {
    $.when(someAjaxCall()).done(function(ajaxResult){
            // after all the pages, covers, and sneaks are uploaded
            // we will now change the status
            //start the ajax
            console.log(ajaxResult);
}

function someAjaxCall() {
    // do something...
    if (someGlobalScopedVariable == true) {
         return $.ajax({
        //this is the php file that processes the data and send mail
        url: url,

        //POST method is used
        type: "POST",

        //pass the data         
        data: data,     

        //Do not cache the page
        cache: false,

        //success
        success: function (json) {....},
     });
    }
}
```

The ajaxResult inside the mainFunction $.when gives me undefined.
Did I do something wrong because i followed this http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/

Comment: maybe it's duplicate with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3709597/wait-until-all-jquery-ajax-request-are-done

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`jQuery.when`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/).

```
var deferred1 = $.ajax({ ... });
var deferred2 = $.ajax({ ... });
var deferred3 = $.ajax({ ... });

$.when(deferred1, deferred2, deferred3).then(
    function(info1, info2, info3) {
        var response1 = info1[0], response2 = info2[0], response3 = info3[0];
        // Do something with response 1, 2, and 3...
    }
);
```

`$.ajax` returns a `Deferred` object. You can pass several `Deferred` objects to `$.when` in order to wait for all of them to complete.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.. but i wrapped my ajax calls within javascript functions. see above for update. So it is causing some issues. I need to wrap my ajax calls because i need to do some other logic BEFORE running those separate ajax calls. I can certainly put everything in 1 giant function but it looks very ugly. Anyway I can maintain separation of concerns while still using jquery.when?

Comment: Does `someAjaxCall()` always `return $.ajax(...)`? Or does it sometimes just exit without returning anything? You might need: `var result = someAjaxCall(); if(result) $.when(result).done(...);`

Comment: I ran this little test in my console while on the StackOverflow website, and it works fine: `var a = $.ajax({ url: '/', success: function(A) { console.log('success', String(A).substring(0, 50)); } }); $.when(a).done(function(A) { console.log('when', String(A).substring(0, 50)); });` . Try it out yourself to confirm `$.when` acts as expected. Then your job is to figure out what's different about your implementation.

Comment: thank you. i finally got it to work. i think further down i need more refactoring.. for now it is good enough. i have nested quite abit of when then, when then, when then almost 4 levels down..